# connection string pull logs from iothub

Tags: python, azure, connection-string, azure-iot-hub

I am new to azure IOT, can someone help me in understanding the logic of how to ***pull the data from the Azure IOT Hub using the connection string?*** ( so by understanding the logic I can write

> python script

).

Note: the data is sent from the edge device to IOT hub in the Azure cloud, now I want to pull the data from the Azure IoT hub to local instance say terminal and at least print one entry in the log file

Answer (score 0):

Messages sent to Azure IoT hub can be retrieved using any Event Hub client, so the first step is getting the Event Hub compatible connection string: in the Azure portal select your IoT hub ➡ click on "Built-in endpoints" ➡ copy the "Event Hub-compatible endpoint".

Once you have the connection string, you can for example use Event Hub Processor Host (EPH) or a simpler Event Hub client, there's some Python examples here:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/examples/eph.py
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/examples/recv.py

EPH is also available in .NET and Java, or you can also use an Akka connector for Scala and Java (e.g. see https://github.com/Azure/toketi-iothubreact). EPH and the Akka connector store the position, so in case of crash they can start from the last known checkpoint.

There are also other ways to retrieve messages, e.g. see [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c), but the details above should help you getting started.